# Unable to detect/click checkout button in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, woocommerce, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a donation checkout page, but the last checkout button does not work. I tried with all locators with different xpath extensions, but still I am facing issues. I am attaching a screenshot of the checkout button and inspectElement.

[Checkout button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8gtx.png)

I tried both ways

```
//With Explicit Wait 
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Sign up now']")))).click();

// With Xpath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='place_order']")).click();
```

Comment: When you do this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='place_order']")).click();` what is the exception you get ?

Comment: Does it work with `driver.findElement(By.id("place_order")).click()`?

Comment: your first line is missing the text() method... try with id and a webdriverwait and expected condition.  Also check for iframes.